# Codeigniter htaccess not working on godaddy?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I recently moved to godaddy Linux hosting and the .htaccess doesn't seem to work. Are there any settings which need to be done for godaddy because the .htaccess was working on local xampp server as well as hostek server.I am getting "404 Not Found" error message.i am using CodeIgniter-2.2.1 framework also i have check mod_rewrite in Loaded Modules in php.ini file was not found enable from server side .

My htaccess file located on root directory where my application is deployed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with CodeIgniter and URI on GoDaddy servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725358/problem-with-codeigniter-and-uri-on-godaddy-servers)

Comment: landing page is also showing `404` error??

Comment: I have tried given discussed solution on stack-overflow and it not working for me.so i have share my application settings and httaccess to figureout the issue.

Comment: @Girish: Yes,please you can check on URL : http://www.eyebrowze.com/

Comment: @SameekMishra check answer below

Comment: @SameekMishra is this a VPS? Do you have access to apache config to see if `AllowOverride` is set to `All`?

Comment: add `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` if you running site from addon url on your hosting

Comment: @PanamaJack:it is share hosting server i don't have access apache config.

Comment: @SameekMishra godaddy has a lot of inconsistencies. Is it an addon site or the primary site on your account?

Comment: @PanamaJack:it's primary site on my account

Comment: This is off topic but I know godady and codeigniter seem to have problems I use arvixe.com and have no issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

**EDIT 01**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725358/problem-with-codeigniter-and-uri-on-godaddy-servers

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working one on Godaddy shared:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/\?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>

  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing     and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path_to/your_website/index.php?$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are the xml tags here case-insensitive?