# Codeigniter remove index.php on https

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I am using godaddy as my server provider and I bought an SSL certificate. It gave me some headache with index.php in my CodeIgniter project. I can not remove the index.php from my url.
I researched around and tried everything I found but nothing works for me, so do not consider it as a double please.


If: https://example.com/index.php/home - works perfectly fine 
If: https://example.com/home
I get a 404 Error. Not Found The requested document was not found on this server.


So far, I have stoped at these conditions in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: did you also change ```$config['index_page'] = '';```in application/config/config.php?

Comment: Does your Apache allow mod_rewrite?

Comment: I am using a windows server on godaddy, so as I read, they do not provide mod_rewrite. So I wrote this in my `.htaccess` files. `Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /` In the documentation of this lines, was written to wait an hour. I will see what happens..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter htaccess not working on godaddy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522085/codeigniter-htaccess-not-working-on-godaddy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Final Result:**

in Helpers:

```
//Force SSL injection
if(!function_exists('force_ssl'))
{
    function force_ssl() {
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
            $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            redirect($url);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

In Controllers call the method: `force_ssl();`

In `.htaccess`, where the `index.php` is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

remove index.php from $config['base_url'].

Then Use this link to remove index.php from url

http://addictors.in/remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter/

then restart server