# no input file specified in codeigniter godaddy hosting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter website. I uploaded it but its not redirecting to any other page. Here is my config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.fantastictravels.co/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. Using godaddy please upgrade your php version. 
follow the link below to help you change php version in Godaddy. https://uk.godaddy.com/help/view-or-change-your-php-version-16090. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to adjust your .htaccess file.  Here are a few similar questions via Stack Overflow that might help your cause:

- [Codeigniter .htaccess in godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572893/codeigniter-htaccess-in-godaddy)
- [Puzzled using codeigniter on shared hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615284/puzzled-using-codeigniter-on-shared-hosting-server)
- [Codeigniter htaccess not working on godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522085/codeigniter-htaccess-not-working-on-godaddy)
- [Problem with CodeIgniter and URI on GoDaddy servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725358/problem-with-codeigniter-and-uri-on-godaddy-servers)

Within those three articles, you will see a few GoDaddy-specific references to the .htaccess rules.  Hope this helps.