# When I upload my CodeIgniter 3.1.2 blog to Godaddy I get a "No input file specified." error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am wondering if anyone knows why I get the following error when uploading my CodeIgniter 3.1.2 blog to my Godaddy hosting server:

No input file specified.

The blog works locally at localhost/blog but does not work at mysite.com/blog

My config looks like the below:

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite/blog';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

and my htaccess file that resides in my 'application' directory looks like the below:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your .htaccess should not be in your application folder, but in the "root" folder with main Codeigniter index.php file.

Comment: I moved it there. It still doesn't work

Comment: Your base URL, is that actually correct? I'm aware you've changed it to hide your actual domain, but I'm just making sure, as `http://mysite/blog` is obviously incorrectly laid out.

Comment: Godaddy and CI have a history. [Here's a link to answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40975957/3585500) for the exact same question.

Comment: @thickguru the URL is laid out  http://example.com/blog. My example leaves out the .com but in the actual file it is in there. So it's not that which is throwing it off

Comment: @ourmandave none of those articles work

Comment: Have you looked at the log files for any error message?

Comment: yeah, it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Try using this htaccess on your root application directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Error must be explained with more details, i don't now if that error is thrown by apache, codeigniter or PHP.